# Finding Which Element of An Array Is an Integer

Tags: algorithms

Given a sorted list of numbers $[a,b,c,d,...z]$ where only one element is an array is an integer, and the rest are not (but rational). Given that you can find the sum from $a$ to any other element in $O(\log(n))$ time (magic), no sum of continuous elements is an integers, and you can not look at any one element separately (through any method), is it possible to find which element is an integer (preferably in $O(\log(n))$. If that is impossible, then I would like a proof to understand why).

Comment: When you need polynomial time to compute the sum from a to some other element, how do you expect a logarithmic bound on this whole process? Do you mean that you can calculate the sum polynomial in some other variable than n?

Comment: @SonneXo Fixed it.

Comment: Additionally: When I'm calculating the sum of [a, ..., k] and the sum of [a, ..., k, j] and subtracting them, I get the value of j. This contradicts "through any method", doesn't it?

Comment: @SonneXo Yes, I knew of that, that's why I said "no other method"-- I wanted to prevent that.

Comment: If this summation process is your only tool and you don't have additional knowledge, I guess you're out of luck. Suppose there were such a way to determine the index of the integer element in $O(log(n))$. Then It can only access constantly many values which does not go well with arbitrarily large lists.

Comment: @SonneXo Hmmm.. what do you mean by "additional knowledge"?

Comment: Currently, the straightforward algorithm is $O(n*log(n))$. However, if you know e.g. that the integer is larger than the sum of rationals, then there might be an algorithm in $O(log(n)^2)$ by binary search. Even if the integer is large and the rationals are small (but the sum of the rationals can be large), there is an algorithm which determines the index of the integer with high probability by splitting the list and looking at the half with a higher sum, also in $O(log(n)^2)$. If you knew that the integer is always in the first 1/p(n) part of the list, then you can get to $O(n*log(n)/p(n))$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know, say $S_r:=a+b+\cdots +r$ and $S_t:=a+b+\cdots +t$, then this does not hepl you in finding out if $s$ or $t$ (or none of them) is the integer: All you know about $s$ and $t$ is that $s+t=S_t-S_r$ (which by assumption is not an integer). So it is still possible that $s=0$ and $t=S_t-S_r$, or $s=S_t-S_t$ and $t=0$, or $s=t=\frac{S_t-S_r}2$, for example. More generally, unless you have queried all valules $S_a:=a$ upto $S_z=a+\cdots +z$, you cannot be sure where the integer lies.

Ok, we have the additional information that $a<b<\ldots <z$, but that doesn't improve the above worst case, e.g., when all numbers are positive the partial sums grow fast enough.